# How can I update sqlite database in django without original migration files and preserve the data in db.sqlite3 at the same time?

Tags: django, sqlite

I am a beginner in django. I accidentally deleted the original migration files and the only remaining related file is db.sqlite3. Now I made some changes to models.py and want to update my database while preserving the previous data in db.sqlite3. How can I do this? Will python manage.py makemigrations work?

Comment: Is your project under some sort of CVS, like Git or Mercurial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nop.

What you can do is run make migrations before your changes.
Run

```
Python manage.py migrate --fake
```

This will make a migration for your table as it is and then mark it as applied. Now you can make your changes and run make migration... Migrate